# Variable Importance for Individual classes in R using Caret

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, caret

I have used a random forest for predicting classes. Now, I am trying to plot variable importance for each class. I have used the below code, but it does not provide me varImp class wise, it is giving me for whole model. Can someone please help me.

Thank you.

```
odFit = train(x = df_5[,-22], 
              y = df_5$`kpres$cluster`,
              ntree=20,method="rf",metric = "Accuracy",trControl = control,tuneGrid = tunegrid
              )
odFit

varImp(odFit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `importance=TRUE` in the `train` function, which is the same to do `importance(odFit)` in the `randomForest` package.

Here a reproducible example:

```
library(caret)
data(iris)

control <- trainControl(method = "cv",10)
tunegrid <- expand.grid(mtry=2:ncol(iris)-1)
odFit = train(x = iris[,-5], 
              y = iris$Species,
              ntree=20,
              trControl = control,
              tuneGrid = tunegrid,
              importance=T
)
odFit

varImp(odFit)
```

and here is the output

```
rf variable importance

  variables are sorted by maximum importance across the classes
             setosa versicolor virginica
Petal.Width   57.21     73.747    100.00
Petal.Length  61.90     79.981     77.49
Sepal.Length  20.01      2.867     40.47
Sepal.Width   20.01      0.000     15.73
```

you can plot the variable importance with `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
vi <- varImp(odFit,scale=T)[[1]]
vi$var <-row.names(vi) 
vi <- reshape2::melt(vi)

ggplot(vi,aes(value,var,col=variable))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need the variable importance "per class", you HAVE TO define `importance=T` in the train() model of your random forest; otherwise, it just gives you the overall important variables in all classes combined. Other than that, there's nothing wrong with your code. Here's the modified version of your own code:

```
odFit = train(x = df_5[,-22], 
          y = df_5$`kpres$cluster`,
          ntree=20,method="rf",metric = "Accuracy",trControl = 
control,tuneGrid = tunegrid, importance=T
          )
odFit

varImp(odFit)
```